# Automatically delete destination file in case of copy failure

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I use NSFileHandler to copy one file to multiply destinations:

```
while([fileMultiCopy copyBlock])
{
    [progressIndicator setDoubleValue: [fileMultiCopy progress]];
    if (stopCopyFlag) { // User clicked stop button
        [fileMultiCopy unlinkTargets]; // Delete partially copied files
        break;
    }
}
```

FileMultiCopy implementation:

```
-(BOOL) copyBlock
{
    NSData *buffer = [sourceHandle readDataOfLength: blockSize];
    if ( [buffer length] == 0) return NO;
    for (NSFileHandle *handle in targetHandleArray)
        [handle writeData: buffer];
    return YES;
}
```

As you can see, I am using NSFileHandle because

1. I want to "read once to write multiply" - file is copied to multiply destinations
2. File is copied by blocks that provides ability to update NSProgessIndicator smoothly and
3. abort copy process by changing stopCopyFlag to YES (from another thread)

If user presses "stop" button, my program deletes partially copied files, but how to delete them in case program is killed by user? I want that files would be copied or not, but not partially.